# Serializing XML into object - "error in xml document (2,2)

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

Yes, I have read other threads on this subject but I am missing something:

I am trying to deserialize an XML document that, in part, contains logged SMS messages.  The XML file takes the format of:

```
<reports>
  <report>
   <sms_messages>
     <sms_message>
     <number>4155554432</number>
     <text>Hi!  How are you?</text>
    </sms_message>
    <sms_message>
     <number>4320988876</number>
     <text>Hello!</text>
    </sms_message>
   </sms_messages>
  </report>
</reports>
```

My code looks like:

```
[XmlType("sms_message")]
public class SMSMessage
{
   [XmlElement("number")]
   public string Number {get;set;}
   [XmlElement("text")]
   public string TheText {get;set;}
}


[XmlType("report")]
public class AReport
{
   [XmlArray("sms_messages")]
   public List<SMSMessage> SMSMessages = new List<SMSMessage>();
}

[XmlRoot(Namespace="www.mysite.com", ElementName="reports", DataType="string", IsNullable=true)]
public class AllReports
{
   [XmlArray("reports")]
   public List<AReport> AllReports = new List<AReport>();

}
```

I am trying to serialize it like this:

```
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AllReports));
TextReader tr = new StreamReader(this.tbXMLPath.text);
List<AllReports> reports;
reports = (List<AllReports>)deserializer.Deserialize(tr);
tr.close();
```

I get the error: "There is an error in XML document (2,2)"  The inner exception states,`<reports xmlns=''> was not expected.`

I am sure it has something to do with the serializer looking for the namespace of the root node?  Is my syntax correct above with the [XmlArray("reports")] ? I feel like something is amiss because "reports" is the root node and it contains a list of "report" items, but the decoration for the root node isn't right? This is my first foray into this area.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about posting your **real** code? you can not declare a member with same class name `AllReports`.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion.  I have to develop this stuff on a forensic box that can't have internet access.  I goofed retyping it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a minimal change to your *non-compilable* code

```
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AllReports));
TextReader tr = new StreamReader(filename);
AllReports reports = (AllReports)deserializer.Deserialize(tr);
```

---

```
[XmlType("sms_message")]
public class SMSMessage
{
    [XmlElement("number")]
    public string Number { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("text")]
    public string TheText { get; set; }
}


[XmlType("report")]
public class AReport
{
    [XmlArray("sms_messages")]
    public List<SMSMessage> SMSMessages = new List<SMSMessage>();
}

[XmlRoot("reports")]
public class AllReports
{
    [XmlElement("report")]
    public List<AReport> Reports = new List<AReport>();

}
```